# Array of floating point values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, floating-point

How can I create array of floating point numbers in Objective-C?
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. For example: `float f[] = {0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 1.3};`

Comment: @KingsIndian - why isn't your comment an answer?

Comment: Or, if you like objects: `NSArray *f = @[ @0.1, @0.2, @0.7, @1.3];`

Comment: You can always put C code in Objective-C anytime, anywhere.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can create a dynamic array (size decided at runtime, not compile time) in different ways, depending on the language you wish to use:

### Objective-C

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f],
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0f],
    nil];
...
[array release];    // If you aren't using ARC
```

or, if you want to change it after creating it, use an `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f]];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0f]];
...
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:99.9f]];
...
[array release];    // If you aren't using ARC
```

Or using the new-ish [Objective-C literals syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html):

```
NSArray *array = @[ @1.0f, @2.0f, @3.0f ];
...
[array release];    // If you aren't using ARC
```

### C

```
float *array = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * 3);
array[0] = 1.0f;
array[1] = 2.0f;
array[2] = 3.0f;
...
free(array);
```

### C++ / Objective-C++

```
std::vector<float> array;
array[0] = 1.0f;
array[1] = 2.0f;
array[2] = 3.0f;
```

Answer (score 3):

For an dynamic approach you can use `NSNumber` object and add it to `NSMutableArray`, or if you need only static array then use suggestions from comments, or use standard `C`.

like:

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [NSMutableArray array];
float yourFloat = 5.55;
NSNumber *yourFloatNumber = [NSNumer numberWithFloat:yourFloat];
[yourArray addObject:yourFloatNumber];
```

and then to retrive:

```
NSNumber *yourFloatNumber = [yourArray objectAtIndex:0]
float yourFloat = [yourFloatNumber floatValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xcode 4.4+, you can try this:

```
NSArray *a = @[ @1.1f, @2.2f, @3.3f];
```

[Here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) is all new literals of LLVM Compiler 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
@interface DoubleArray : NSObject

@property(readonly, nonatomic) NSUInteger count;

@property(readonly, nonatomic) double *buffer;

- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

- (instancetype)initWithCount:(NSUInteger)count NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

- (double)valueAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;

- (void)setValue:(double)value atIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;

@end

@implementation DoubleArray

- (void)dealloc
{
    if (_buffer != 0) {
        free(_buffer);
    }
}

- (instancetype)initWithCount:(NSUInteger)count
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _count = count;
        _buffer = calloc(rows * columns, sizeof(double));
    }
    return self;
}

- (double)valueAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    return *(_buffer + idx);
}

- (void)setValue:(double)value atIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    *(_buffer + idx) = value;
}

@end
```

It's a basic array. You can extend this with more complex features like appending, indexed removal etc.